# how to get post category id

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

i have a loop in my index.php
and i want to add category id to post class

i try'd many code but i did't got the right code
here is what i have:

```
<?php if (have_posts()):?>
    <?php $catID = get_the_category('id');?>
    <ul>
        <?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
        <li class="cat<?php get_the_category( $post->ID );?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <?php $src= wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array(250,220), false, ''); $thumbnailSrc = $src[0]; ?>
                <img class="thumbnail" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumbnailSrc;?>&w=250&h=220&zc=1q=100" alt="">
                <span class="hover"></span>
                <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                <h3>توضیحات بیشتر<?php echo $catID; ?></h3>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're inside a loop, you should use `the_category()` instead of `get_the_category()`

```
 <?php if (have_posts()):?>

        <ul>
            <?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
            <li class="cat<?php the_category();?>">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <?php $src= wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array(250,220), false, ''); $thumbnailSrc = $src[0]; ?>
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumbnailSrc;?>&w=250&h=220&zc=1q=100" alt="">
                    <span class="hover"></span>
                    <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                    <h3>توضیحات بیشتر<?php echo $catID; ?></h3>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif;?>
```